# Define global variable in theme file and call that variable in plugin file

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I am creating a custom WordPress theme and what I want is to define a global variable in theme file and call that variable in plugin files.
I searched on google and many StackOverflow posts about this topic for instance :

creating function in the theme file

```
<?php
function ww_new(){
global $ww_new;

$ww_new = $post_slug;
}
add_action('wp_roles_init', 'ww_new');
?>
```

and call it in the plugin file

```
global $ww_new;
echo $ww_new;
```

but this approach doesn't work for me.
Any clue regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing about your problem is the loading priority. By default, Plugins are loaded before the theme. So, when you define a global variable in the `functions.php` it is not available in plugins code like your example.

```
global $ww_new;
echo $ww_new;
```

But you can use the defined global variable if you make sure your code is running after defining it. It is possible by using hooks.

in `functions.php` change the code to

```
function ww_new(){
    global $ww_new;
    $ww_new = $post_slug;
}

// Define it immediately after `init` in a high priority.
add_action('init', 'ww_new', 1, 1);
```

and then, in your plugin codes, you can use it like

```
 add_action( 'init', 'ww_new_usage', 10, 1 );

 function ww_new_usage() {
    global $ww_new;
    // Use the variable here.
 }
```

Please read the **$priority** part of the [add_action developer docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).